# Momentary output from turning on and off a switch

Tags: capacitor, resistors, switches, relay, automotive

I am trying to wire something up for my car so everything here is going to be running off 12/14 V and draw is well under 1 A, probably in the range of 200 mA.

I am trying to find a simple way of turning a switched output (-) into pulses (also -) but not just a pulse when the switch is turned on but also a pulse when it is turned off.

I need is a switch to be "pressed" when the reverse lights turn on, and then gets "pressed" when the lights turn off.

I have no idea what would be the simplest way to make this. I was looking on the 12 V at those relay diagrams and was going to use that but, it would be so jank requiring like 4-5 relays all with resistors and caps wired in. I was surely hoping there was a much simpler method using a small breadboard or something.

If anyone could mock something up that would be amazing.

Comment: How long does your momentary "switch" need to be on? Is one side of your switch connected to a power rail or to ground? Please add this information to your question.

Comment: A monostable multivibrator would do the trick for you.  Whats the 'load' here (i.e. where are these pulses going).  and what's the ramifications if you get either false triggers or you miss real ones  i.e. how good does it need to be?

Comment: What is "jank"?

Comment: An edge-detector circuit like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55327429/how-to-create-an-asynchronous-edge-detector-in-vhdl could work.  The principle being that presenting a "normal" and a time-delayed version of the input signal to an XOR gate will cause the output to be high for as long as it takes for the second copy of the signal to travel through the delay line.  Implementation in an automotive environment will likely require non-trivial input protection and "massaging".